# in rust, how to limit possible range of a struct u8 integer field?

Tags: rust, struct

Example

```
pub struct Coord {
    row: u8,
    col: u8,
}
```

How can I set `row` and `col` to be able to accept only values in range `(0..3)` (so from 0 to 2) ?

I'd like to force programmer to avoid invalid valued during initializtion.

> Another use case is for Planet Earth coords, where long and latitude have a fixed valid range.

Comment: By giving it a constructor: `impl Coord { fn new(r : u8, c: u8) -> Option<Coord> { ... } }`

Comment: @BitTickler: expand your answer please,, I am at my first days in rust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You express this by either...

1. provide a constructor, which does the checks for valid values and returns an `Option<Coord>`
2. create new types `Row` and `Col`, which only accept small values. And then use those types in your struct.

ad 1.:

```rust
impl Coord {
  pub fn new(row: u8, col: u8) -> Option<Self> {
    if row < 3 && col < 3 {
      Some(Coord { row, col })
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}
```

ad 2.:

```rust
struct Row { 
  value: u8
}
struct Col {
  value: u8
}
impl Row {
  pub fn new(value: u8) -> Option<Row> {
    if value < 3 {
      Some(Row {value})
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}
impl Col { // ... same as for Row }

// Now the impl for Coord
impl Coord {
  pub fn new(r : Row, c : Col) -> Self {
    Coord { row: r.value, col: c.value }
  }
}
```

Most would probably opt for solution 1. While some might opt for solution 2, because it only allows creating a Coord from valid `Row` and `Col` values.

In the case of `Latitude` `Longitude` you would have the same two options.